# Primefaces pegar valor escolhido no autocomplete

Tags: java, primefaces, autocompletar

Estou trabalhando com o `AutoComplete` do `primefaces` e estou com um problema. Por exemplo, o usuário digita no combo uma palavra *OSW* e aí o `dropdown` lista todos os contratos que tem como fornecedor o termo *OSW*.

Até aí tudo bem, só que quando o usuário seleciona no dropdown o contrato eu não consigo pegar o conteúdo selecionado por ele, só consigo pegar a palavra que ele digitou pra achar o contrato.

*Meu código:*

```
 <p:autoComplete id="inputTextFornecedorComplete" dropdown="true"forceSelection="true"
                                        minQueryLength="3" size="82" maxResults="15" 
                                        value="#{contratoNotaFiscalBean.sessionBean.itemPagina.contrato.chaveContrato}" class="autoCompletar"
                                        completeMethod="#{contratoNotaFiscalBean.completeText}" 
                                        rendered="#{contratoNotaFiscalBean.sessionBean.operacaoInclusao}">
      <f:ajax event="itemSelect" render="selectOneMenuChaveContrato" execute="@this"/>
  </p:autoComplete>
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia de como posso incrementar esse código para pegar o valor escolhido no `dropdown`?

Comment: Na tela é preenchido o valor correto?

Comment: Sim fica tudo correto, porém no Bean quando vou acessar essa varável {contratoNotaFiscalBean.sessionBean.itemPagina.contrato.chaveContrato} ao invés de vir o valor selecionado no drop down vem só o valor que o usuário digitou :(

Comment: Você debugou? Se não tente isso e veja o que está chegando.

Comment: Debuguei, por exemplo: Se eu digitar OSW no drop down ele lista todos os contratos do fornecedor OSW aí o conteúdo que vem pra mim é OSW e não o que está listado no dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoal obrigado a todos pela ajuda, achei o problema. Tive que trocar esse codigo:

```
 <f:ajax event="itemSelect" render="selectOneMenuChaveContrato" execute="@this"/>
```

Por esse:

```
 <p:ajax event="itemSelect" />
```

Obrigado a todos!